# want to redirect subdirectory from htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
example.com/watch.php?id=1995/english-videos <- this url i want to redirect like this -> www.example.com/watch/1995/english-videos
```

i want to redirect only `watch.php` and i want to get value after `id=`

at present my htaccess file
/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^col3negmovie.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.col3negmovie\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

if can someone help me for do this one... thanks. and i want to 301 Redirect

example.com/watch.php?id=`1995/english-videos` <- want to get this value and redirect to this url `www.example.com/watch/1995/english-videos` like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^col3negmovie\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.col3negmovie.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+watch\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ watch/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^watch/(.+?)/?$ watch.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: @anubhava Pardon I have a `awk` [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039264/working-with-arrays-in-bash-and-do-stuff)...