# working with arrays in bash and do stuff

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I am writing a bash script and need help. This is what I tried:

With the help of @merlin2011

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <absolute-path> <number>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

#find . -name "$2" -exec mv {} /some/path/here \;
find $1 >> /tmp/test
for line in $(cat `/tmp/test`); do
    echo $line | mv $2 awk -F"/" '{for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) if ($i == "$2") print $(i-1)}'
done
```

Now I want to check the result of `find` command from array and then if there were a directory named `2010` then get the absolute path of it. For ecxample:

```
arr[1]="/path/to/2010/file.db"
```

Then I want to rename `2010` to parent directory `to`. My pattern is:

```
arr[1]="/path/to/2010/file.db"
arr[2]="/path/test/2010/fileee.db"
arr[3]="/path/tt/2010/fileeeee.db"
.
.
.
arr[100]="/path/last/2010/fileeeeeee.db"
```

Result should be:

```
mv /path/to/2010/ to
mv /path/test/2010 test
mv /path/tt/2010/ tt
.
.
.
mv /path/last/2010 last
```

UPDATE:

Totally I want to know how to get a variable inversely in `awk`...

```
/path/to/dir1/2010/file.db
```

I want to search in `absolute path` then find 2010 and rename it in previous path with `/` `pattern like : awk -F"/" {print [what?]}`

tell awk my state is 2010 then print one variable before it by knowing splitter is `/`

## UPDATE

The files dirs and subdirs pattern are:

```
/path/to/file/efsef/2010/1.db
/path/to/file/hfjh/sdfsf/2010/2.db
/path/to/file/dsf/sdhher/aqwe/sfrt/2010/3.db
.
.
.
/path/to/file/kldf/2010/100.db
```

I want to rename all 2010 dirs to their parent then `tar` all `.db`

This is what exactly I want :)

Comment: I just updated. Let me know if that does what you are trying to do.

Comment: So you want to pass `/path/to/dir1/2010/file.db` to awk and search `2010`? If `2010` is found then what do you want to do next?

Comment: Thanks... If 2010 [second argument] found I want to rename it to the parent directory...

Comment: So you want: `mv /path/to/dir1/2010/file.db dir1`?

Comment: I want to do: mv $2 [parent directory of $2]

Comment: But why awk? This can be done in BASH itself

Comment: Ok I thought it is good using awk...If it is possible with bash please  help..

Comment: How do you see this [one](https://github.com/MortezaLSC/Programming/blob/master/test.sh)?:

Comment: @MortezaLSC, You make a good point. I thought he was just trying to use `awk` to learn it. :P

Comment: The last 4 lines of your posted script each contain semantic errors and your descriptive text is far too focused on HOW you think you need to do whatever you're trying do do (e.g. `I want to check the result of find command from array` and `I want to know how to get a variable inversely in awk`) rather than WHAT you're trying to do. Please just clean it up to show some sample input, expected output and a brief description of WHAT it is you need to do. As-is, you'll probably get an answer telling you how to do the wrong thing in a valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks...Firstly I thought I could do that with arrays, after that our friends told me other ways...So I asked it again in other question...You and other guys answered my question...Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses only the OP's update. My best interpretation is that you are trying to get `awk` to print the value `dir1` inside the string `/path/to/dir1/2010/file.db`. The following line will achieve it.

```
awk -F"/" '{for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) if ($i == "2010") print $(i-1)}'
```

I tested using the following command, which will output `dir1`.

```
echo /path/to/dir1/2010/file.db | awk -F"/" '{for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) if ($i == "2010") print $(i-1)}'
```

Based on your update, you should surround the `awk` command with the `backtic` operator.

```
mv $2 `awk -F"/" '{for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) if ($i == "$2") print $(i-1)}'`
```

Comment: Thanks..very good..but: How to tell rename 2010 to the result of awk here?

Comment: I will update based on the assumption that your array is correct.

Comment: i liked your solution. Way to go @merlin2011

Comment: By your help: It [THIS](https://github.com/MortezaLSC/Programming/blob/master/test2.sh) working for me?

Comment: @MortezaLSC, I just updated. I screwed up the backtic placement lol.

Comment: I don't have linux now..I want to be sure this is working or not...sorry..I would be thankful if you put the whole script in your answer...

Comment: @MortezaLSC, I can only test this part. I do not have your directory structure on my system, so I can't verify whether the other parts of your script are correct.

Comment: @MortezaLSC, Use the last line in my updated answer. Keep in mind I am assuming that `echo $line` always has a `2010` in it. If that is not true, then the `mv` command will simply throw and error because it will only have one argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
        To implement, we have to do the recursive folder search.

        It should be combination of two commands like find and mv




        find . -name "2010" -exec mv {} /some/path/here \;


Other way shared by merlin2011
    mv $2 awk -F"/" `'{for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) if ($i == "$2") print $(i-1)}'`
```

Comment: This should be: `find $1 -name "$2" -exec mv {} [Here should be the parent directory of 2010] \;`

Comment: Ok...I want to use awk to find the parent directory...I am not good at `awk`

Answer (score 1):

Here is awk command:

```
awk -F"/$2/" '{split($1, a, "/"); system("echo mv " $0 " " a[length(a)]);}' <<< "$1"
mv /path/to/dir1/2010/file.db dir1
```

Once you're satisfied remove `echo` in system command.

Comment: please check [this](https://github.com/MortezaLSC/Programming/blob/master/test.sh)

Comment: That's what it does. You can set `s="$2"`. Isn't `dir1` parent dir of `2010`?

Comment: Yes but this is a variable itself...may be dir1 maybe anything else...so the command `mv /path/to/dir1/2010/file.db dir1` I think shouldn't work

Comment: Yes it can be anything. In above command if `s='/path/to/anything/2010/file.db'` then output will be: `mv /path/to/anything/2010/file.db anything` What else do you expect?

Comment: Ok...Could you possibly put the whole script? I am not able write it because of some problems...Thank you very much

Comment: I actually don't know what is `$1` and `$2` in your script and why are you doing `find $1`?

Comment: $1 is absolute path that I want to find all subdirs...$2 is a number that can be 2010 or anything can be founded in my absolute path to filnaly find parent dirs

Comment: find $1 is showing all dirs and subdirs and files of an absolute path. After that I want to tell script main dir is 2010($2) than I want to remove all 2010 dirs to their parent dir. Firstly I used arrays for doing that.But I think with `for loop` it is possible as well

Comment: Thank you for your help..Yes I tried and doesn't work..now please see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040109/rename-specific-pattern-of-files-in-bash) surely you can understand what I exactly want...thank you

Comment: I just got back, posted an answer on other question also.