# How to get the last part of dirname in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, dirname

Suppose I have a file `/from/here/to/there.txt`, and want to get only the last part of its dirname `to` instead of `/from/here/to`, what should I do?

Answer (score 171):

You can use `basename` even though it's not a file. Strip off the file name using `dirname`, then use `basename` to get the last element of the string:

```
dir="/from/here/to/there.txt"
dir="$(dirname $dir)"   # Returns "/from/here/to"
dir="$(basename $dir)"  # Returns just "to"
```

Comment: How to print 1 directory back like /from/here/ ?

Answer (score 29):

The opposite of `dirname` is `basename`:

```
basename "$(dirname "/from/here/to/there.txt")"
```

Answer (score 24):

Using `bash` string functions:

```
$ s="/from/here/to/there.txt"
$ s="${s%/*}" && echo "${s##*/}"
to
```

Answer (score 15):

Using Bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), you could do this:

```
path="/from/here/to/there.txt"
dir="${path%/*}"       # sets dir      to '/from/here/to' (equivalent of dirname)
last_dir="${dir##*/}"  # sets last_dir to 'to' (equivalent of basename)
```

This is more efficient since no external commands are used.

Comment: I just tested this. On FreeBSD here are my results:
Code:
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/svn/repos

path="$1"
echo "${path}"

dir="${path%/*}"
echo "${dir}"

actual="${dir##*/}"
echo "${actual}"
----------------------------------------
Results:
$ ./makerepo.sh /var/test
/var/test
/var
var
$
------------------------------------
Fail! Sorry. Seemed a good method but not a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

An `awk` way of doing it would be:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "/from/here/to/there.txt"
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F'/'` sets field separator as "/"
- print the second last field `$(NF-1)`
- `<<<` uses anything after it as standard input 
  ([wiki explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign#Triple_less-than_sign))

Answer (score 4):

Pure BASH way:

```
s="/from/here/to/there.txt"
[[ "$s" =~ ([^/]+)/[^/]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
to
```

Comment: Will not work if file has no dot `.`. Will not work if directory has dot `.`. Keep it simple and use slash `/` as delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

One more way

```
IFS=/ read -ra x <<<"/from/here/to/there.txt" && printf "%s\n" "${x[-2]}"
```

Comment: Simpler to use: `printf "%s\n" "${x[-2]}"`.

Answer (score 2):

This question is something like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040109/rename-specific-pattern-of-files-in-bash).

For solving that you can do:

```
DirPath="/from/here/to/there.txt"
DirPath="$(dirname $DirPath)"
DirPath="$(basename $DirPath)"

echo "$DirPath"
```

As my friend said this is possible as well:

```
basename `dirname "/from/here/to/there.txt"`
```

In order to get any part of your path you could do:

```
echo "/from/here/to/there.txt" | awk -F/ '{ print $2 }'
OR
echo "/from/here/to/there.txt" | awk -F/ '{ print $3 }'
OR
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer is absolutely correct for the question asked. In a more generic case with the needed directory in the middle of a long path, this approach leads to a hard to read code. For example :

```
dir="/very/long/path/where/THIS/needs/to/be/extracted/text.txt"
dir="$(dirname $dir)"
dir="$(dirname $dir)"
dir="$(dirname $dir)"
dir="$(dirname $dir)"
dir="$(dirname $dir)"
dir="$(basename $dir)"
```

In this case one can use:

```
IFS=/; set -- "/very/long/path/where/THIS/needs/to/be/extracted/text.txt"; set $1; echo $6
THIS
```