# using bash to extract a folder name

Tags: bash

I've a series of mp3s set out in folders like so

> ```
> /mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ aaa/01.mp3
> /mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ 02/01.mp3
> /mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ Chemist/01.mp3
> ```

is there a way I can use sed to grab the folder names

> ```
> DJ aaa
> DJ 02
> DJ Chemist
> ```

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162299/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-dirname-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **parameter expansion** with **substring extraction** as an alternative to `dirname/basename'; Here is a quick example reading all your directory names from a datafile:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "\n The following directories were isolated:\n\n"

while read -r line || test -n "$line" ; do

    pname="${line%/*}"      # remove filename from line
    lastd="${pname##*/}"    # remove up to last '/'

    printf " %-12s  from  %s\n" "$lastd" "$line"

done <"$1"

printf "\n"

exit 0
```

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/mp3dirs.txt
/mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ aaa/01.mp3
/mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ 02/01.mp3
/mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ Chemist/01.mp3
```

**output:**

```
$ ./lastdir.sh dat/mp3dirs.txt

 The following directories were isolated:

 DJ aaa        from  /mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ aaa/01.mp3
 DJ 02         from  /mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ 02/01.mp3
 DJ Chemist    from  /mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ Chemist/01.mp3
```

Comment: If you're going the bash way, another option is to use `read` to do the splitting for you: `IFS=/ read -r -a line_ary; do ...` and you'll get the part of the directory you want in `line_ary[-2]`.

Comment: Yep, I played with a lot of ways. I like the `-2` index. That is one I did not consider. I had set `IFS` when using a `for` loop for processing, but for the completely opposite reason. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `basename` with `dirname`:

```
 f="/mnt/media/Music1/DJ_Mixes_01-71/DJ aaa/01.mp3"
 d=$(dirname "$f")
 echo "$(basename "$d")"
```

gives you `DJ aaa`

Comment: And you still need to quote the command substitution in the `echo` statement: `echo "$(basename "$d")"`, otherwise your code is subject to pathname expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Through sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*\/(.*)\/.*$/\1/' file
```

Through awk:

```
awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

Through grep:

```
grep -Po '.*\/\K.*(?=\/.*$)' file
```

Through cut:

```
cut -d'/' -f6 file            # for fixed number of fields
```

or

```
rev file |cut -d'/' -f2 |rev  # for any length of fields
```

Through [cuts](https://github.com/arielf/cuts/):

```
cuts -2 file
```

Comment: In your `cut` solution, you're assuming a fixed number of fields. This is not good.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes but I didn't want to use `rev` command there. but updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like below. The `\(` and `\)` will mark the pattern from DJ to the last character before the `/`

```
sed 's#.*\(DJ [[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)/.*#\1#g'
```

Results

```
DJ aaa
DJ 02
DJ Chemist
```