# How to get a path to folder where a file is location given a full path to it?

Tags: bash

I want to get a path to a file location given a full path to that file in bash:

```
path="/home/user123/Documents/folder1/file1.txt
```

Given that full path I want to extract the "/home/user123/Documents/folder1" part. Should I just parse the path and throw away the part after the latest "/" or is there a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162299/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-dirname-in-bash#

Comment: use [dirname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dirname` command in Linux will do that for you:

```
$ dirname /home/user123/Documents/folder1/file1.txt
/home/user123/Documents/folder1
```

To get the other piece, you can use `basename`:

```
$ basename /home/user123/Documents/folder1/file1.txt
file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using sed:

```
 echo "$path" | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
```